# Reuse of form data in different Angular components?

Tags: angular

In my Angular app I have a bunch of different dialog modals where form data is entered. Some groups of data repeat on a lot of different forms (example: person info with name, email, address, etc.). I want to separate the form part into one component and then reuse it within different modal components.

The markup part is simple enough but I am unsure of how to pass the data to its parent component.  Different things would happen on the submit button depending on which modal component the form data component would be added to.

I am looking for a tutorial or some kind of high level explanation of how I could achieve this

Comment: Place submit button not in the `form.component.html` but in every other `some-component.component.html`'s

Comment: That makes sense but how do I pass the data entered in form.component.html to some-component.html ?

Comment: Your FormControl objects holds the state - just get it and do whatever

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Concerning your question about "how to pass the data entered in form.component.html to some-component.html"**

If your **form.component.html** is the template of a child component of the parent component **some-component.ts**, you could easily follow the official documentation ([link here](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-listens-for-child-event)). That is to say :

1. For the child component :

   - You need an EventEmitter property which is marked as output (the type of data emitted may be something else than a boolean)

     ```
     @Output() customEvent = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
     ```
   - Some kind of method which emits our event

     ```
     myMethod() {
       this.customEvent.emit(someData);
     }
     ```
2. When you have set up your child component, let's look into its parent :

   - You need an attribute in your parent template which corresponds to the name of your @Output() attribute (here, we gave the name "customEvent" to our attribute)

     ```
     <child-component (customEvent)="handleEvent($event)"></child-component>
     ```
   - Then, you can handle the event when triggered

     ```
     handleEvent(data) {
       // do something
     }
     ```

Try to look at this link for a complete example : http://learnangular2.com/outputs/